# Symfony2 - Using CSS assets in PHP templates

Tags: php, css, templates, symfony, assets

I have installed my assets using:

```
php app/console assets:install web/
```

and the public resources have been moved to the web folder without problems.

I now want to access these assets from my php view scripts, but can only find twig examples. Can anyone show me how to accomplish this....

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/acmedemo/css/demo.css') }}" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

in a php view script??

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
href="<?php echo $view['assets']->getUrl('bundles/acmedemo/css/demo.css') ?>"
```

Comment: Thanks mate! I actually found it in the docs about a minute after posting this. Found it here [link](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/templating.html#linking-to-assets) Thanks for replying though!